# How to create a folder with a date or build number using Agent-based template in MS Release Management

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

Using agent-based release templates, not vNext, how do I configure a "Create Folder" item so that it incorporates the date into the folder name, e.g. "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\backups\MyApp\02-03-2015\".

Preferably, I would like the build number instead of the date but I believe it's only available to vNext templates. -edit- unless you're using components

I'm trying to implement some backup and rollback logic as part of the my release pipeline. I want to copy the existing web code to a backup folder, just in case the copy from the drop location to the web server fails.  On rollback, I'll copy from my backup, to the server.  I've seen the build to Test fail when someone tampers with the files, presumably because the security is missing the RM service account.

Alternative solutions that solve the problem may be accepted as well. I'd like to keep successive backup foldcers and have them deleted manually.  I do **NOT** want to reuse the same folder for backup and restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are using a **component** $(BuildNumber) will work in agent-based templates. To create a folder you would create a component based on **Windows Common IO** and when you use it in the Release Template the **Action = Create** and **FileFolderName = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\backups\MyApp\$(BuildNumber)**.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I'm going to elaborate on this component to also copy the files over.  Wish me luck.

Comment: For those reading and want to make a backup folder with the contents, its simpler to use the 'XCopy Deployer' tool instead of the Windows Common IO.  The XCopy will create the folder for you.  If you want to share the component with multiple apps,set the build drop location to \, and then alter the arguments line to " _ Source Folder _ "  " _ Destination Folder _ ".  (Use double underscores).  Enjoy.  Thanks to Graham for answering my original question and getting me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad that it worked Bill, and thanks for posting about XCopy. I'll check that out as we have a scenario where we want to build software releases to folders for environments that we're not ready to automate the deployment to.